# Finding a maximum likelihood function

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\dots,X_{n}$
  represent a random sample from a distribution with probability density function $$f(x;\theta)=\frac{x}{\theta}e^{-x^{2}/2\theta}\hspace{1em}x>0
 $$

Find the maximum likelihood function.

I did:

$$L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i};\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{\theta}e^{-x_{i}^{2}/2\theta}
 $$

$$\ell(\theta) = \ln(L(\theta))
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(-\frac{x_{i}^{2}\theta}{2}+\ln x_{i}-\ln\theta\right)
 $$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\delta\ell}{\delta\theta} & = & \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(-\frac{x_{i}^{2}\theta}{2}+\ln x_{i}-\ln\theta\right)\right)\\
0 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}^{2}-2\theta}{2\theta^{2}}\\
2\theta^{2} & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}-2\theta\\
2\theta^{2}+2n\theta & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

but it feels wrong. Is it wrong? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the distribution family and maximum likelihood estimate definition:

$$\displaystyle f(x; \theta) = \frac{x}{\theta} e^{-x^2 / (2\theta)}$$

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(\theta) =\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{\theta} e^{-x_i^2 / (2\theta)}$$

Your derivation of the log likelihood should look closer to this:

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{l}(\theta) = - n \ln{\theta} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left ( \ln{x_i}  + \frac{-x_i^2}{2\theta} \right)$$

And consequently your optimization step of taking the derivative of the log likelihood like:

$$\displaystyle \frac{d \mathcal{l}}{d\theta} = -\frac{n}{\theta} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i^2}{2\theta^2}$$

Which when solving for a derivative of zero, gives you your estimator

$$\displaystyle \theta =  \frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 = \frac{1}{2} \overline{ X^2 }$$

(Where $\overline{ X^2 }$ is the mean of the samples squared, not the square of the mean of the samples.)

Answer (score 0):

Your third-to-second (counting from last) equalities has an error. It should be

$$0  =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}-2\theta \implies \theta = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}$$

Two observations:

1) ML estimator is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance) with respect to any invertible transformation. That means that you could instead solve the alternative parametrization ($\beta=1/\theta$)

$$f(x;\beta)=x \beta \,e^{-x^{2} \beta/2}\hspace{1em}x>0$$

which is slightly easier, and then recover $\hat \alpha = 1/\hat \beta$.
Become familiar with this trick, here, the convenience is minor, sometimes is big.

2) Don't just blindly "derive and equal to zero" to find the maximum. Sometimes that's not enough to find the global maximum of a function. Ask first about the domain of the parameter, if the function is differentiable everywhere (what about the domain borders?), and check if the critical point found is really a maximum.